# Expression must have same datatype in UNION Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, union

There two queries whose output I need as a resultant set for using union but in one query there is `map_id` which is of data type varchar2(60) and in query 2 this column is missing. Map_id is actually a sequence which is stored in the table query is using. Query 2 has a table which has no map_id for this i have written something like :

```
select * from 
    (select map_id,person_id,emp_num from table_abc)
UNION
    (SELECT ROWID MAP_ID , PERSON_ID, EMP_NUM FROM TABLE_XYZ)
```

Now error is coming:

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 9
```

How can I use any incremental value in query 2 so that the datatype matches between the two queries?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ROWID` has a different type from `map_id`, whatever the type of `map_id`, because `ROWID` produces columns of a separate type.

Since the type of `map_id` is something to which `ROWID` could be cast, you can fix this by casting `ROWID` to `varchar2(60)`:

```
select * from 
    (SELECT map_id, person_id, emp_num FROM table_abc)
UNION
    (SELECT CAST(ROWID AS VARCHAR2(60)) MAP_ID, PERSON_ID, EMP_NUM FROM TABLE_XYZ)
```

If `map_id` is not expected to have values that could match any of the `ROWID`s from the other table, consider using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. This would let Oracle skip filtering for uniqueness, speeding up your query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are selecting 3 values map_id,person_id,emp_num in query 1 and 4 values ROWID MAP_ID , PERSON_ID, EMP_NUM in query 2 as well as syntax error in second query. The RowID and Map_ID is not seperated with , in the query 2

So you have the error.

If you want to display ROWID in from the second query, Create a dummy column for ROWID in query 1 like below

```
SELECT *    FROM ( SELECT 'ROWID' = NULL
               ,map_id
               ,person_id
               ,emp_num             FROM table_abc       ) UNION ( SELECT ROWID
       ,MAP_ID
       ,PERSON_ID
       ,EMP_NUM     FROM TABLE_XYZ )
```

Comment: Hi @karthik.venkatramana - No query 2 has rowid as map_id so that there is an incremented sequence in query 2....

Comment: @divya.trehan573 is your column name rowid map_id? if yes then please cast the column with the appropriate datatype. It will work. Something like cast(rowid map_id AS float). Else if the column name is just rowid or map_id, you can use it directly. Also let us know what is the datatype of the columns so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cast()` as follows:

```
    select * from 
    (select map_id,person_id,emp_num from table_abc)
    UNION
    (SELECT cast(ROWID AS varchar(20)) as MAP_ID , PERSON_ID, EMP_NUM FROM TABLE_XYZ)
```